# Using Django "rules" with CBVs doesn't seem to work

Tags: django, permissions, predicate

Each restaurant can have multiple managers.

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    ...
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='restaurants_which_they_manage')
```

Only restaurant managers can change a restaurant listing. I'm using [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules) to enforce this. I've got a predicate that creates a nice verbose "is_restaurant_manager" reference :

```
@rules.predicate
def is_restaurant_manager(user, restaurant):
    return user in restaurant.managers.all()
```

And here is the permission :

```
rules.add_perm('restaurants.change_restaurant', is_restaurant_manager)
```

Finally, here is my view :

```
class RestaurantChange(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = Restaurant
    permission_required = 'restaurants.change_restaurant'
    fields = ['name', 'description', ]
```

I've got two tests.

Test A checks that the permission works properly :

```
self.assertEqual(rules.has_perm('restaurants.change_restaurant', self.user, self.restaurant), True)
```

This first test passes successfully.

Test B attempts to access the url with a valid user  :

```
url = reverse('restaurants__restaurant_change', kwargs={'pk': self.restaurant.key,})
response = self.client.get(url)
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Test B fails, as I get a redirection. This also happens if I try to access the url via the browser. The redirection goes to the login process, as though the user didn't have permission to access the view.

What's wrong with my code ?

Comment: How do you set up the users and assign the permissions in the tests?

Comment: Hello Alasdair, I use `User.objects.create_user`, then `Restaurant.objects.create`, followed by `restaurant.managers.add(user)`. 

I don't think the issue comes from the tests, since I can reproduce it in the browser.

Comment: How do you log-in the user in the test?

Comment: @Alasdair, i'm using the following : `login = self.client.login(username='monsieur.patate', password='potato25')`

Comment: Are you sure the login works? Your code appears to be ok to me, so either I can't spot the problem, you've hit a bug, or you aren't including enough information in your question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Even if I login manually and reproduce the steps in the browser I get the same redirect. Here is the full repo if you want to have a look (and thank you). https://github.com/tavola-restaurants/Tavolia/blob/dev/restaurants/tests.py

Comment: Did you configure properly as described in [best practices](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules#best-practices) your settings?

Comment: I just set it up that way, at least I think so, and it did not fix anything unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was playing around with django-rules to see if it suits the needs of a project and run into the issue you added on django-rules.

After adding a pdb trace in the tests and going through your settings I noticed the following:

https://github.com/tavolia/Tavolia/blob/7aca6530a8a301b8b81999095cf7535c363dd484/_project/settings.py#L121-L124

https://github.com/tavolia/Tavolia/blob/7aca6530a8a301b8b81999095cf7535c363dd484/_project/settings.py#L142-L145

The second link is an assignment, overriding authentication backend set in the previous assignments.

By adding the `'rules.permissions.ObjectPermissionBackend'` to the second set of backends, the tests pass without error.

[image: code diff and test run]

I made a pull request on github to solve this issue: https://github.com/tavolia/Tavolia/pull/5

Cheers!

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you !

Comment: What exactly was wrong? Your blobs dont exist anymore.

Comment: You can see it on the screenshot. Instead of adding the `allauth....` backend to the list of backends, he was replacing all backends with a tuple containing the `allauth....` backend as single entry.