# Using Django “rules” with CBVs don't work

Tags: django, permissions, predicate, django-2.0

I am running into a problem using rules with CBV. I initialized rules like this:

```
rules.add_perm('core.change_user', is_myuser)
```

Where:

```
@rules.predicate
def is_myuser(user):
    print('Checking inside from rules')
    return False
```

And I am calling:

```
class UserUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'forms/user_form.html'
    permission_required = 'core.change_user'
```

However this is not working. I have checked the solution from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672950/using-django-rules-with-cbvs-doesnt-seem-to-work) and I correctly have:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'rules.permissions.ObjectPermissionBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]
```

I am not able to figure out the problem here. Even the debug message inside my predicate `is_myuser` doesn't print

I also tried changing the permission name and using `add_rule()`.
I am using Django==2.0.8 and rules==2.0

Other pieces of Code:

Initialize Permissions in AppConfig:

```
class CoreConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app.core'
    verbose_name = 'My App Config'


def ready(self):
    from .rules import init_rules
    import logging
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info('Initializing permissions')
    rules.add_perm('core.change_user', is_myuser)
```

I am getting `Initializing permissions` in logs.

When I check for permission in `get_context_data` of CBV

```
print(f"User has permission: {self.request.user.has_perm(self.permission_required, self.get_object())}")
```

Output: User has permission: True

Expected Output: User has permission: False

Note: I have created an issue regarding the same on Django-rules. [Github](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules/issues/93)

Comment: Where do you import `PermissionRequiredMixin` from?

Comment: `from rules.contrib.views import PermissionRequiredMixin`